# TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

Tags: php, html

Estoy tratando de generar un reporte PDF utilizando [`TCPDF`](https://tcpdf.org/), pero al ejecutar mi código salta el siguiente error:

> TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

Por favor, ¿me pueden dar una mano para determinar el error, generar el PDF y lograr imprimirlo?. Desde ya, esteré muy agradecido.

El código que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

**index1.php**

```
<?php  
 function busca_datos()  
 {  
      $output = '';  
      $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "usuario", "password", "personal");  
      $sql = "SELECT id_cliente, cedula, nombres, tel, dir FROM clientes ORDER BY id_cliente ASC";  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {       
      $output .= '<tr>  
                          <td>'.$row["id_cliente"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["cedula"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["nombres"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["tel"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["dir"].'</td>  
                     </tr>  
                          ';  
      }  
      return $output;  
 }  
 if(isset($_POST["create_pdf"]))  
 {  
      require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');  
      $obj_pdf = new TCPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);  
      $obj_pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);  
      $obj_pdf->SetTitle("Export HTML Table data to PDF using TCPDF in PHP");  
      $obj_pdf->SetHeaderData('', '', PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);  
      $obj_pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));  
      $obj_pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));  
      $obj_pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');  
      $obj_pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);  
      $obj_pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, '5', PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);  
      $obj_pdf->setPrintHeader(false);  
      $obj_pdf->setPrintFooter(false);  
      $obj_pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 10);  
      $obj_pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 12);  
      $obj_pdf->AddPage();  
      $content = '';  
      $content .= '  
      <h3 align="center">Export HTML Table data to PDF using TCPDF in PHP</h3><br /><br />  
      <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">  
           <tr>  
                <th width="5%">ID</th>  
                <th width="30%">Name</th>  
                <th width="10%">Gender</th>  
                <th width="45%">Designation</th>  
                <th width="10%">Age</th>  
           </tr>  
      ';  
      $content .= busca_datos();  
      $content .= '</table>';  
      $obj_pdf->writeHTML($content);  
      $obj_pdf->Output('reporte.pdf', 'I');  
 }  
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Exportando a PDF desde PHP</title>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">            
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:700px;">  
                <h3 align="center">Exportando a PDF desde PHP usando TCPDF en PHP</h3><br />  
                <div class="table-responsive">  
                     <table class="table table-bordered">  
                          <tr>  
                               <th width="5%">ID</th>  
                               <th width="30%">Name</th>  
                               <th width="10%">Gender</th>  
                               <th width="45%">Designation</th>  
                               <th width="10%">Age</th>  
                          </tr>  
                     <?php  
                     echo busca_datos();  
                     ?>  
                     </table>  
                     <br />  
                     <form method="post">  
                          <input type="submit" name="create_pdf" class="btn btn-danger" value="Crear PDF" />  
                     </form>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>
```

Comment: tu consulta esta correcta? tiene datos $output?

Comment: Hola @josego. Sí, $output trae los datos; agregue un echo $output antes de la línea que tiene: $obj_pdf->writeHTML($content);    y se muestran correctamente todos los datos

Comment: te genera un pdf normal. Osea con un hola mundo solo. Proba hacerlo de la manera mas simple. Porque puede ser que no te genera luego ningún pdf.

Comment: Intenta meter un `die();` justo debajo de la linea `$obj_pdf->Output('reporte.pdf', 'I');` así podrás ver más claramente la/s salida/s que hubo durante el proceso.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es muy probable que tu problema sea debido a que aparece algún tipo de mensaje de advertencia antes de que generes el PDF o quizá haya un espacio en blanco antes del `<?php` inicial, etc.

Puedes silenciar los errores con `error_reporting(0)` y `ini_set('display_errors', 0)`, pero creo que es mejor que mandes los mensajes de advertencia al log del servidor (en vez de sacarlo por pantalla) para depurar el problema posteriormente. También vamos a bloquear la salida de datos al cliente hasta la finalización del script:

```
if (isset($_POST["create_pdf"])) {
  ob_start();
  error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
  ini_set('display_errors', 0);
  ini_set('log_errors', 1);
  /* ...
   Resto del código que genera el PDF
     ... */
  /* Limpiamos la salida del búfer y lo desactivamos */
  ob_end_clean();
  /* Finalmente generamos el PDF */
  $obj_pdf->Output('reporte.pdf', 'I');
}
```

Prueba si con eso te funciona, pero no olvides revisar el log de tu servidor para averiguar cuál era el problema raíz que sufrías (quizá una variable o macro sin asignar).

Comment: Hola @OscarGarcia, gracias por tu ayuda.

dejé el código como:

 if(isset($_POST["create_pdf"]))  
 {  
      error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
      display_errors(false);
      log_errors(true);
      
      require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php'); 
      $obj_pdf = new TCPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false); 

pero al mandar a generar el pdf aparece el siguiente mensaje:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function display_errors()

Comment: Disculpas, son parámetros que se configuran en `php.ini` o en un `.htaccess`, como escribí el código de memoria no caí en que debo usar [`ini_set`](http://php.net/ini_set). Ya he cambiado el ejemplo.

Comment: Gracias por la corrección, pero sigue arrojando el mismo mensaje original de error: TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

Comment: ¿Tienes un espacio en blanco antes del `<?php` del comienzo del script? ¿Haces un `echo` o cualquier otra salida de datos al navegador en alguna parte de tu script? Todo apunta a que el origen es ese ya que hemos desactivado la salida de mensajes de advertencia que puedan molestar. Sólo se me ocurre matar la mosca a cañonazos... usemos [`ob_start`](http://php.net/ob_start) para bloquear la salida prematura de datos al cliente. Voy a modificar el código para ilustrarte cómo hacerlo.

Comment: encontre algo, que es una suma de detalles y estoy verificando . . . tendré en cuenta lo que me mencionas del espacio en blanco antes del <?php . .  .. estoy revisando y en un momento comento cómo me fue y cual era el problema, si es que puedo hacerlo funcionar

Comment: Ok, y de paso comprueba que el PHP no está en UTF-8 con [BOM](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_de_orden_de_bytes) ya que el BOM cuentan como caracteres iniciales que provocan la salida al cliente de datos y la generación de cabeceras.

Comment: Ya se logró generar el PDF, tal como me lo advirtió Oscar García, había un espacio en blanco antes del <?php inicial, ahora sólo me falta arreglar temas de formato, pero entiendo que es configuración.
Muchas gracias Oscar García, @josego y Marcos Gallardo por el tiempo y conocimientos que me han regalado al ayudarme a solucionar ese problema; bendiciones y muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4):

Escribe esto antes de generar el pdf, para limpiar cualquier texto anterior

```
ob_end_clean();
$pdf->Output($pdf_name, 'I');
```