# Problema con TCPDF "TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file"

Tags: php, tcpdf

Al momento de cambiar de servidor local la webapp dejo de funcionar correctamente el TCPDF y arroja el error mencionado anteriormente, el entorno es el mismo, xampp en windows y el navegador chrome. Dejo el código por si alguien me puede ayudar, las otras respuestas no funcionaron.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ob_start();
require_once "../../../Controllers/ventas.controlador.php";
require_once "../../../Models/ventas.modelo.php";
require_once "../../../Controllers/clientes.controlador.php";
require_once "../../../Models/clientes.modelo.php";
require_once "../../../Controllers/usuarios.controlador.php";
require_once "../../../Models/usuarios.modelo.php";
require_once "../../../Controllers/productos.controlador.php";
require_once "../../../Models/productos.modelo.php";

class imprimirFactura
{

    public $codigo;

    public function traerImpresionFactura()
    {

        //TRAEMOS LA INFORMACIÓN DE LA VENTA
        $itemVenta  = "id";
        $valorVenta = $this->codigo;

        $respuestaVenta = ControladorVentas::ctrMostrarVentas($itemVenta, $valorVenta);

        $fecha     = $respuestaVenta["created_at"];
        $productos = json_decode($respuestaVenta["products"], true);
        $descuento = $respuestaVenta['discount'];
        $neto      = number_format($respuestaVenta["value"], 2);
        $impuesto  = number_format($respuestaVenta["tax"], 2);
        $propina   = 0;
        switch ($respuestaVenta['tip_type']) {
            case 'porcentual':
                $propina = $respuestaVenta['value'] * $respuestaVenta['tip_value'] / 100;
                break;
            case 'personalizada':
                $propina = $respuestaVenta['tip_value'];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        $total   = $propina + $respuestaVenta['total'];
        $total   = number_format($total, 2);
        $propina = number_format($propina, 2);

        //TRAEMOS LA INFORMACIÓN DEL CLIENTE

        $itemCliente  = "id";
        $valorCliente = $respuestaVenta["client_id"];

        $respuestaCliente = ControladorClientes::ctrMostrarClientes($itemCliente, $valorCliente);

        //TRAEMOS LA INFORMACIÓN DEL VENDEDOR

        $itemVendedor  = "id";
        $valorVendedor = $respuestaVenta["vendor_id"];

        $respuestaVendedor = ControladorUsuarios::ctrMostrarUsuarios($itemVendedor, $valorVendedor);

        //REQUERIMOS LA CLASE TCPDF

        require_once('tcpdf_include.php');

        $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

        $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
        $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

        $pdf->AddPage('P', 'A7');

        //---------------------------------------------------------

        $bloque1 = <<<EOF
<table style="font-size:5px; text-align:left">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:160px;">
                Fecha: $fecha
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table style="font-size:8px; text-align:center">
    <tr>

        <td style="width:160px;">

            <div>


                <br>
                <br>
                <b>BON SANDWICH</b>
                <br>
                Sucursal: Mercado del Norte
                <br>
                Dirección: Calle 56 No. 55-96
                <br>
                Local: 28

            </div>

        </td>

    </tr>


</table>
<table style="font-size:7px; text-align:center">
    <tr>

        <td style="width:160px;">

            <div>
                <br>
                Ticket de venta N.$respuestaVenta[bill_number]
                <br>                    
                Cliente: $respuestaCliente[name]
                <br>
                Vendedor: $respuestaVendedor[name]

                <br>

            </div>

        </td>

    </tr>


</table>
EOF;

        $pdf->writeHTML($bloque1, false, false, false, false, '');

        // ---------------------------------------------------------


        foreach ($productos as $key => $item) {

            $valorUnitario = number_format($item["price"], 2);

            $precioTotal = number_format($item["total"], 2);

            $bloque2 = <<<EOF
<table style="font-size:7px;">

    <tr>

        <td style="width:160px; text-align:left">
        $item[name] 
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td style="width:160px; text-align:right">
        $ $valorUnitario Und * $item[quantity]  = $ $precioTotal
        <br>
        </td>

    </tr>

</table>


EOF;

            $pdf->writeHTML($bloque2, false, false, false, false, '');

        }

        // ---------------------------------------------------------

        $bloque3 = <<<EOF
<table style="font-size:7px;">

    <tr>

        <td style="width:160px; text-align:left">
        Observaciones:
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td style="width:160px; text-align:center">
        $respuestaVenta[comments]
        <br>
        </td>

    </tr>

</table>
<table style="font-size:6px; text-align:right">

    <tr>

        <td style="width:80px;">
             DESCUENTO: 
        </td>

        <td style="width:80px;">
             $descuento %
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td style="width:80px;">
             NETO: 
        </td>

        <td style="width:80px;">
            $ $neto
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td style="width:80px;">
             IMPUESTO: 
        </td>

        <td style="width:80px;">
            $ $impuesto
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td style="width:80px;">
             PROPINA: 
        </td>

        <td style="width:80px;">
            $ $propina
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td style="width:160px;">
             --------------------------
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td style="width:80px;">
             <b>TOTAL:</b> 
        </td>

        <td style="width:80px;">
            $ $total
        </td>

    </tr>

</table>
<table style="font-size:6px; text-align:center">
    <tr>

        <td style="width:160px;">
            <br>
            <br>
            SOMOS RÉGIMEN SIMPLIFICADO Y NO REQUERIMOS RESOLUCIÓN DE LA DIAN
            <br>
            <br>
            <b>Gracias por su compra, bon appetit.</b>
            <br>
            <br>
            <b>Sistema POS ptlab.co</b>
        </td>

    </tr>

</table>



EOF;

        $pdf->writeHTML($bloque3, false, false, false, false, '');

        // ---------------------------------------------------------
        //SALIDA DEL ARCHIVO 

        /* Limpiamos la salida del búfer y lo desactivamos */
        //$pdf->Output('factura.pdf', 'D');
        ob_end_clean();
        $pdf->Output('factura' . $respuestaVenta['bill_number'] . '.pdf');

    }

}

$factura         = new imprimirFactura();
$factura->codigo = $_GET["idVenta"];
$factura->traerImpresionFactura();

?>
```

[image: Inspector del error]

Comment: Autoexplicativo. Cuando imprimes en pantalla en PHP, ya no puedes generar otro output.

Comment: Y posible solución  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36801/tcpdf-error-some-data-has-already-been-output-cant-send-pdf-file?rq=1

Comment: Ya revise esas soluciones, no encuentro que estoy imprimiendo, por mas que reviso no veo nada, ya quite mensajes que puedan salir y no tengo espacio en blanco antes del inicio del bloque php :(

Comment: De hecho funciona perfectamente en el servidor local donde lo cree, cuando lo migre, a otro servidor local, con el mismo entorno, ocurrio el problema