# Buen día a todos tengo problemas con este error "TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file"

Tags: php

Tengo el problea de un código para generar una factura en php donde todo está bien pero al querer impriimir la factura me muestra el error "TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file"

Este es el código utilizado:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['user_login_status']) AND $_SESSION['user_login_status'] != 1) {
        header("location: ../../login.php");
        exit;
    }
    /* Connect To Database*/
    include("../../config/db.php");
    include("../../config/conexion.php");
    $id_factura= intval($_GET['id_factura']);
    $sql_count=mysqli_query($con,"select * from facturas where id_factura='".$id_factura."'");
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($sql_count);
    if ($count==0)
    {
    echo "<script>alert('Factura no encontrada')</script>";
    echo "<script>window.close();</script>";
    exit;
    }
    $sql_factura=mysqli_query($con,"select * from facturas where id_factura='".$id_factura."'");
    $rw_factura=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_factura);
    $numero_factura=$rw_factura['numero_factura'];
    $id_cliente=$rw_factura['id_cliente'];
    $id_vendedor=$rw_factura['id_vendedor'];
    $fecha_factura=$rw_factura['fecha_factura'];
    $condiciones=$rw_factura['condiciones'];
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../html2pdf.class.php');
    // get the HTML
     ob_start();
     include(dirname('__FILE__').'/res/ver_factura_html.php');
    $content = ob_get_clean();

    try
    {
        // init HTML2PDF
        $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'LETTER', 'es', true, 'UTF-8', array(0, 0, 0, 0));
        // display the full page
        $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
        // convert
        $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
        // send the PDF
        $html2pdf->Output('Factura.pdf');
    }
    catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
        echo $e;
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Es en php, que será lo que me genera el error?

Muchas gracias a todos por la ayuda de antemano, se les agradece y saludos y un fuerte abrazo desde El Salvador

Comment: ¿Esto responde a tu pregunta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36801/tcpdf-error-some-data-has-already-been-output-cant-send-pdf-file